# How to pass a file id (or fid) as a Views argument through a Panel?

Tags: 7, panels, views, media

I'm trying to create two block views in a panel variant, in order to create a photo gallery ("Stage" view plus "All Thumbnails" view).  The main problem I have right now is the "Stage" view which takes two contextual filter arguments: **/node-id/file-id**

**Some background:**
Each gallery is a content type I've created called "Media Collection", which has the following fields: Title, Description, Media.  The "Media" field is a multi-value field which allows me to attach multiple images (or other files) thanks to the D7 Media module.  Therefore, my plan is to have the URL send two arguments to generate the 1) correct "Media Collection" node and 2) the correct image (file) from that node's Media field, hence: **/node-id/file-id** URL arguments.

So, when I set it all up in the Views UI, everything works fine.  I pass in 1745/2899 or whatever and I get the correct image attached to that media collection that I am targeting.  It is when I try to set this up in the Panel that things don't work out.  The reason is because the Panel Pane view config window does NOT reveal a file-id as a possible Contextual Filter (CF) for the 2nd CF dropdown.  The closest I can get to this is "Media" which appears as a field of the node context.  So basically I need to get more granular and be able to tell the panel that I am passing not a field but an entity reference or file ID.  If I could do it via a Media field: Delta, I would do that as an alternative approach, but that doesn't show up in the Panels pane config either.

What do I do?